# Undefined control sequence \color using xwatermark

Tags: errors, color, xwatermark

I'm trying to use the `xwatermark` package.  I have a document like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

\begin{document}

\newwatermark[allpages]{UNAPPROVED}

Foo

\end{document}
```

Building this with `tectonic` fails:

```
$ tectonic demo.tex
note: this is a BETA release; ask questions and report bugs at https://tectonic.newton.cx/
Running TeX ...
error: something bad happened inside TeX; its output follows:

===============================================================================
(demo.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 4
Babel <3.20> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(size10.clo)) (xwatermark.sty (catoptions.sty (pdftexcmds.sty (infwarerr.sty)
(ifluatex.sty) (ltxcmds.sty) (ifpdf.sty))) (fix-cm.sty (ts1enc.def))
(picture.sty) (graphicx.sty (keyval.sty) (graphics.sty (trig.sty) (graphics.cfg
) (xetex.def))) (atbegshi.sty) (fancyhdr.sty) (atveryend.sty) (ltxkeys.sty)
(framed.sty)) (hyperref.sty (hobsub-hyperref.sty (hobsub-generic.sty))
(ifxetex.sty) (auxhook.sty) (kvoptions.sty) (pd1enc.def) (hyperref.cfg)
(url.sty)) (hxetex.def (puenc.def) (stringenc.sty) (rerunfilecheck.sty))
No file demo.aux.
(nameref.sty (gettitlestring.sty))

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...e \@tempdima \@parboxrestore \color
                                                  {\wmk@textcolor }\cptdimde...
l.10 \end{document}

No pages of output.
Transcript written on demo.log.
===============================================================================

error: the TeX engine had an unrecoverable error
caused by: halted on potentially-recoverable error as specified
```

How do I use `xwatermark` (with `tectonic`)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `\usepackage{xcolor}`

Comment: Thanks.  That did it.  Want to make it an answer so I can accept?  Also would be nice how I would figure out it's "xcolor" I need from the given error or from the xwatermark docs.

Comment: There are only two (that I know of) packages that define `\color`: `color` and `xcolor` (this is a widely used command and two widely used packages, so it was easy to spot; lesser known commands are trickier to find out). And as I said in the answer, this looks like a bug: if `xwatermark` requires `xcolor` to work, then it should `\RequirePackage{xcolor}`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\color` is defined by LaTeX's base `color` support package, so loading it will get rid of that error. However this package provides only basic colour support, and `xwatermark` seems to need the extended features from the `xcolor` package (so adding `\usepackage{xcolor}` is a safe bet).

Though this looks a lot like a bug in `xwatermark`: if the package requires `xcolor` then it should explicit load `xcolor` instead of trusting the user to do it...